# Error en C respecto a librerias

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
main()
{
    char palabra[32];
    char ordenado[32];
    int longitud;
    int i;
    int j;
    char x;

    printf("Dame una palabra:\n");
    scanf("%s",palabra);

    longitud=strlen(palabra);
    strcpy(ordenado,palabra);
    /*copiamos la cadena de origen (palabra) para no modificarla
    y trabajar sobre otra (odenada)*/

    /*El metodo es de bubblesort, comparamos una a una las letras*/
    for(i = 1; i < longitud; i++)
        for(j=0; j<longitud-i; j++)
        {
            if((tolower(ordenado[j]))>(tolower(ordenado[j+1])))
                /*Para pasar la letra sea minuscula o mayuscula*/
            {
                x=ordenado[j];
                ordenado[j]=ordenado[j+1];
                ordenado[j+1]=x;
            }
        }
    printf("Tu palabra es: %s\n",palabra);
    printf("Tu palabra ordenada es: %s\n",ordenado);
    system("pause");
}
```

Adjunto imagen del error que me sale al compilar y ejecutar

[image: Error]

Comment: En el primer `for`... ¿no le faltan las llaves?

Comment: te faltan las llaves del primer `for`

Comment: Ya puse las llaves, me sale error en la línea `longitud=strlen(palabra);` y en la línea `strcpy(ordenado,palabra);` me dicen que no se ha declarado la función

Comment: Las llaves están bien. No necesita ni las del del 2º for.

Comment: Pon, al principio del archivo, `#include <string.h>`

Comment: ¿Esto es C o C++?

Comment: @NaCl compila y funciona en **ambos**, aunque use el *estilo* C. Deberías de dejar la etiqueta C++.

Comment: @Trauma aunque por claridad siempre serían bien recibidas :). Por otro lado pienso como NaCl... la etiqueta correcta es C.

Answer (score 4):

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char palabra[32];
    char ordenado[32];
    int longitud;
    int i;
    int j;
    char x;

    printf("Dame una palabra:\n");
    scanf("%s", palabra);

    longitud = strlen(palabra);
    strcpy(ordenado, palabra);
    /*copiamos la cadena de origen (palabra) para no modificarla 
    y trabajar sobre otra (odenada)*/

    /*El metodo es de bubblesort, comparamos una a una las letras*/
    for (i = 1; i < longitud; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < longitud - i; j++) {
            if ((tolower(ordenado[j]))>(tolower(ordenado[j + 1])))
                /*Para pasar la letra sea minuscula o mayuscula*/ {
                x = ordenado[j];
                ordenado[j] = ordenado[j + 1];
                ordenado[j + 1] = x;
            }
        }
    printf("Tu palabra es: %s\n", palabra);
    printf("Tu palabra ordenada es: %s\n", ordenado);
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Al revisar los errores que se generan, podemos encontrar estos:

> `strlen` undeclared
>
> `strcpy` undeclared
>
> `system` undeclared

Estos errores nos indican que hay ciertas funciones que necesitan que se incluya la libreria respectiva, para poder usarlas.

Para ello incluimos entonces:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

En `string.h` encontramos las funciones `strlen()` y `strcpy()`.

En `stdlib.h` encontramos la funcion `system()`

### Nota:

Generalmente para permitir una portabilidad del codigo, o bien, por seguir un estandar, la funcion `main()` se suele declarar asi:

```
int main()
```

Ya que esta funcion debe retornar al sistema operativo un valor de retorno, que generalmente suele ser 0, indicando una ejecucion exitosa del programa.